# Filter or query in powershell $null properties

Tags: powershell, filter, null, exchange-server

This query works like a charm:

Get-CASMailbox | Where ActiveSyncAllowedDeviceIDs -ne $null

This returns me all Mailboxes which have at least one allowed ActiveSync Device

But I'm interested into the opposite. I want to get all Mailboxes which have no Active Sync Device. So I did following:

Get-CASMailbox | Where ActiveSyncAllowedDeviceIDs -eq $null

But this query returns me nothing. How can I query the empty ones?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work:

Get-CASMailbox | Where {-Not $_.ActiveSyncAllowedDeviceIDs}